# Android Management API devices installation, deletions, etc

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, mdm

I am currently working with an Android Management API (MDM) project. Unfortunately, I cannot find a solution for these issues:

1. Let say I have ***force_installed*** an app into my enrolled device - **How can I delete the app remotely?**
2. If I have a few devices with the same policy applied, how can I trigger only one device for installation, deletion, updates, etc..

Answer (score 2):

1. To `Delete` an app remotely you just have to remove it from the `Policy`

```
"applications": [
    {
      "packageName": "com.whatsapp",
      "aliasName": "WhatsApp",
      "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
      "lockTaskAllowed": true,
      "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
    }
 ]
```

For example if you have `WhatsApp` installed, just remove it from the policy and it will uninstall.

2. If you have the same `policy` attached to multiple devices you cannot individually control each device. To do so you'd have enroll each device with a `new policy`